# How to access internet. in serial mode for huawei modem on RPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, at-command, huawei-mobile-services

I am using huawei E8372 modem, I have successfully switched from Hilink mode to serial mode to send AT commands but in this mode I am unable to access internet. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of your modem and the contract of your internet provider?